# SSAS Deployment fails on Metadata due to using wrong data Source

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, sql-server-2012, ssas-tabular

When I try to deploy a SSAS Tabular project from my local machine to the integration server I get an error in the metadata. It's a many to many error that I had previously solved, and I know I solved it because the Tabular project can be processed locally. That is the crux of the issue, when I process the project, it is using the correct data source, but when I try to deploy the project it uses a previous data source that is no longer valid.

Steps I've taken:

1. I Went into the model, selected existing connections, and modified them to  connect to the correct environment (they were previously pointed at the invalid environment) this allowed me to process the data, but I still can not deploy correctly.
2. I created a new configuration in the configuration manager, to no avail.
3. I looked for other areas where the source DB is listed, I haven't found any, which is frustrating because I know it's somewhere.

Is there a cache I'm missing or a setting I didn't check, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't anything to do with credentials? How do you know that when deploying it uses a previous data source?

Comment: As sure as I can be when it's not working, I'm an admin on both the current environment and the prior environment, and the error is specifically metadata related (many to many).